# How to use xbindkeys to activate a minimized window?

Tags: xbindkeys

In Autokey I used this script to be run on pressing hotkeys [Alt+X] and Activating window named 'Add'

```
window.activate('Add', switchDesktop=False, matchClass=False)
```

How is it  possible to do it in xbindkeys?

Answer (score 0):

xbindkeys is a tool to change keyboard layout. I am not sure if you can assign scripts to hotkeys with xdotool, but it is certainly possible in most desktop environments and even window managers to assign a script or a shell command to a custom hotkey.

You can use either wmctrl or xdotool to search existing windows by window title or window class and act on them, in your case, bring them to the foreground.